# Is there any advantage to use a viewModelScope or liveDataScope when observing LiveData from a Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, coroutine, android-architecture-components

Can somebody please explain if there is any advantage to use a viewModelScope or liveDataScope when observing LiveData from a Room database?

My current understanding is, that I have to insert, query, delete or update data to/from a Room database from a thread that is different from the UI thread. Therefore I have been using Kotlin Coroutines with viewModelScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO) { ... } in a MVVM architecture containing a ViewModel and a Repository - similar to the setComplete function in the viewModel code below.

However, in the TasksViewModel class (from this project https://github.com/android/architecture-samples)  tasksRepository.observeTask(taskId).map { computeResult(it) } returns a LiveData object and it is called without wrapping a coroutine scope around it.

Do I understand it correct, that I can omit Coroutines to observe LiveData, because LiveData runs on a background thread anyway?

If so, is there any advantage to wrap a viewModelScope or liveDataScope around tasksRepository.observeTask(taskId).map { computeResult(it) } and how should that look like in the following ViewModel?

**TasksViewModel.kt**

```
class TaskDetailViewModel(
    private val tasksRepository: TasksRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _taskId = MutableLiveData<String>()

    private val _task = _taskId.switchMap { taskId ->
        tasksRepository.observeTask(taskId).map { computeResult(it) }

...

    fun setCompleted(completed: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val task = _task.value ?: return@launch
        if (completed) {
            tasksRepository.completeTask(task)
            showSnackbarMessage(R.string.task_marked_complete)
        } else {
            tasksRepository.activateTask(task)
            showSnackbarMessage(R.string.task_marked_active)
        }
    }

...

    private fun computeResult(taskResult: Result<Task>): Task? {
        return if (taskResult is Success) {
            taskResult.data
        } else {
            showSnackbarMessage(R.string.loading_tasks_error)
            null
        }
    }
...
}
```

**DefaultTasksRepository.kt**

```
class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {

...

    override fun observeTasks(): LiveData<Result<List<Task>>> {
        return tasksLocalDataSource.observeTasks()
    }

...

}
```

**LocalTasksRepository.kt**

```
class  TasksLocalDataSource internal constructor(
    private val tasksDao: TasksDao,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksDataSource {

...

    override fun observeTask(taskId: String): LiveData<Result<Task>> {
        return tasksDao.observeTaskById(taskId).map {
            Success(it)
        }
    }

...

}
```

**TasksDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface TasksDao {

...

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE entryid = :taskId")
    fun observeTaskById(taskId: String): LiveData<Task>

...

}
```

**ToDoDatabase.kt**

```
@Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ToDoDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun taskDao(): TasksDao
}
```

I hope my question is understandable?

Comment: The context on which you call suspending Room methods is not important. Room switches the context on each call automatically, using something equivalent to `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. And `viewModelScope` is actually the main (UI) thread. A reason to use `viewModelScope` is because it provides proper cancellation matching its component's lifecycle.

Comment: Forgot to mention Dispatcher.IO. I edit the question accordingly, thanks. I understand the point with the context. But what happens if don't use viewModelScope and the activity or fragment is destroyed and finished? Is there anything I have to take into account? Because I saw multiple example projects from Google's Codelabs where viewModelScope is not used when observing LiveData.

Comment: You don't need coroutines to work with LiveData, so long as you call its functions from the main thread. If you observe a LiveData, the observer is automatically removed when its lifecycle ends. Though some would suggest transitioning from LiveData to Flow at the Dao and Repository levels so they are not dependent on an Android-specific component.